# How to get the latest Build number for a particular Stage through Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a **Multi-Stage** YAML Pipeline along with 3 deployment stages **Dev**, **QA** and **Prod**. Now Using **Azure DevOps REST API**, I would like to fetch the latest **Build Number** when a particular **deployment Stage** got deployed successfully. For example, fetch the **Build Number** of the last successful **QA** stage deployment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Build number is the name of the completed build, different stages in same build have `same` build number. You can use predefined variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)` to get the value([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)).

[image]

If you'd like to distinct different stages, you can get `stage` name instead with predefined variable `$(System.StageName)`. Sample below, combined the buildnumber and stage name.

```
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Dev
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - bash: |
         echo $(Build.BuildNumber)-$(System.StageName)


- stage: QA
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - bash: |
         echo $(Build.BuildNumber)-$(System.StageName)

- stage: Prod
  dependsOn: [Dev,QA]
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - bash: |
          echo $(Build.BuildNumber)-$(System.StageName)
```

For example, the output for `Dev` stage:

[image]

Edit:

Regarding to get the last the build number of the last successful deployment of a particular deployment stage, it's more complicated.

Step1: You need to get all build url with `build id` in the target build definition with rest api "[Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)", it also list the build number for each build run.

`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionid}&api-version=6.1-preview.7`

[image]

Step2: after you get all build url, you can use below rest api to check the stage result with build url(more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61405716/14996050).):

we use number to represent the result: 0: succeeded, 1: succeded with issues, 2: failed, 3: canceled, 4: skipped, 5: abandoned

`Get https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_build/results?buildId={id}&__rt=fps&__ver=2`

[image]

You need to validate the stage result for each build with a loop, from high build id to lower, until it find the stage result is successful, then return the build number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as mentioned, I wanted to fetch the latest Build Number that has been made for a particular stage using the DevOps REST API.

Comment: Do you want to fetch the `last` successful build number based on the stage name? Or current build number if the stage is successful?

Comment: Sorry, the description might not have been clear enough. I edited it. So would like to fetch the build number of the `last successful deployment` of a `particular deployment stage`. For instance, get the last build number when `QA deployment stage` got deployed successfully. During that build phase, `Prod` may have not been deployed.

Comment: I have updated the comment, please check.